# Callout mediator and send mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am confused with the above two mediators. What is the difference between `Call out` mediator and `send` mediator in wso2ESB mediators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually callout mediator makes a blocking call, it cannot use the default non-blocking http/s transports based on Java NIO. But the send mediator makes aynchronous call for services. This is the basic difference between them. For more about those you can refer the documentation;
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Mediators

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [callout mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Callout+Mediator) WSO2 ESB team has introduced another brand new mediator to serve blocking call to Backend. "[Call Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Call+Mediator)" is very similar to the [Callout Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Callout+Mediator), which performs a blocking external service invocation during mediation. Unlike the Callout mediator, the Call mediator leverages the non-blocking transports for much greater performance.